# HTML/CSS hamburger menu wont dissapear when width over 480px

Tags: html, css, menu

On my website i have hamburger menu which shows if width is under 480px. Everyting works fine expect one thing. If width is under 480px and I click hamburger menu and then i make width of a screen more than 480px and click to close menu hamburger button wont dissapear. 
This is CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

.links .hamburger {
    display: block;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
 .hamburger {
display: none;

}
```

Comment: You only need one media query, not two.

Comment: You're not closing the braces of your media rules.

Answer (score 1):

If the default is block than you only need to add

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .hamburger {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're forgetting the closing brackets for the media queries:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .links .hamburger {
    display: block;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .links .hamburger {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Also your max-width query targets a more specific CSS selector (.links .hamburger), it's better to use the same selector.

Comment: Not working, brackets were fine, just mistake while copying.

Comment: Have you tried using the same CSS selector for showing and for hiding?

Comment: Yes. The code is working, it only doesnt hide when i close the menu after i resize the window and width is more than 480px.

Answer (score 0):

Just set it as display: none; without the media query

```
   .hamburger {
       display: none;
   }

    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
       .hamburger {
           display: block !important;
       }
    }
```

you might need !important inside the display block of the media query

Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ugm77w7s/1/